# What happens if I change solver or train prototxt while training

Tags: caffe, solver

In Caffe, what happens if I change some parameters in the solver or train prototxt while training a network using the given files (and e.g. run another training using the updated solver/train prototxt)? Does it affect the training or is the content of the files loaded in the beginning and the training is unaffected by the later changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prototexts are read from disk the moment you call `caffe train` from command line or `caffe.Net`/`caffe.get_solver` via Python interface, and never again. The solver or network is instantiated using those parameters, and any further changes to the files are irrelevant (until you manually reload, of course).